# validate if another field greater than

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

```
<tr>
    <td>Bill:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= select_tag 'bill_hours', options_for_select(@hours, 0)  %>:<%= select_tag 'bill_minutes', options_for_select(@minutes, 0)  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nonbill:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= select_tag 'nonbill_hours', options_for_select(@hours, 0)  %>:<%= select_tag 'nonbill_minutes', options_for_select(@minutes, 0)  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
     <%=select_tag 'cat_type_id',options_for_select(@cat_type_list,@selected_cat_type), {:prompt=>"Select Category Type"}%><br/>
      <select id="activity_category_id" prompt="Select Category" name="activity[category_id]" style="width:300px;">
        <option value=''>Select Category</option>
        <%@cat_list.each do |c|%>
        <option value="<%=c.id%>" <%=(!@activity.nil? && @activity.category_id==c.id) ? "selected" : "" %> class="<%=c.cat_type_id.nil? ? '':c.cat_type_id%>"><%=c.short_description.nil? ? c.description : c.short_description%></option>
        <%end%>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Location:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%=select 'activity', 'location_id', @locations, {:prompt=>"Select Location"}, :required => true %><br/><%=select 'activity', 'location_modifier_id', @location_mods, {:prompt=>"Select Modifier"}, :required => true %></td>
  </tr>
```

I have the above code as a sample. How can I make the `"activity, location_id"` required if and only if `"bill_hours"` or `"bill_minutes"` or `"nonbill_hours"` or `"nonbill_minutes"` is > 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `:if` key to use a condition on your validation.

**In your model:**

```
validates_presence_of :location_id, if: -> do 
  %i(bill_hours bill_minutes nonbill_minutes nonbill_hours).any? { |attr| read_attribute(attr) > 0 } 
end
```

Comment: I get **undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass** when i try your suggestion.

Comment: Are `bill_hours` `bill_minutes` `nonbill_minutes` `nonbill_hours` all columns in your model?

Comment: you were right, needed to change to (bill_duration nonbill_duration)

Thanks Anthony